Python function to run in background
I have two functions, "one" and "two". I want function "one" to run in the background as  two runs. Basically, one executes, and while it's waiting, execute two.
import time

def one(msg, a):
    time.sleep(a)
    print(msg)
def two(msg, a):
    time.sleep(a)
    print(msg)

one("Hello, ", 2) # Run this in the background as the other function runs
two("World!", 1)

I tried coroutines but it didn't really work out for me because one ran after the other.

have a look to multiprocessing or threading, depending on the nature of the tasks, either CPU- or IO-bound

You can use multi-threading to have one function run in the background.  You can use multiprocessing as well, but in most scenarios, simply creating a thread is better than creating an entire separate process. In your case, you can change your code to look like this:
import time, threading

def one(msg, a):
    time.sleep(a)
    print(msg)
def two(msg, a):
    time.sleep(a)
    print(msg)

thread = threading.Thread(target=one, args=("Hello, ", 2))
thread.start()
two("World!", 1)

If however, you want to use multi-processing, you can use this code instead:
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def one(msg, a):
    time.sleep(a)
    print(msg)

def two(msg, a):
    time.sleep(a)
    print(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Process(target=one, args=("Hello, ", 2))
    p1.start()
    
    p2 = Process(target=two, args=("World!", 1))
    p2.start()

Both of these will achieve the same result.

"same result"... it depends on what "same" means

@cards In this scenario, it will make the same result.  As you mentioned in the comments, they are not always the same
